# Fundamental Lemma of CdV proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Do you know an easy proof of the following result?

*Let $f\in L^1_{loc}(U)$, where $U$ is an open subset of the $n$-dimensional euclidean space. If $$\int_U f\varphi dx=0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall\varphi\in C^{\infty}_C(U)$$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere in $U$*.

I only know a proof which makes use of the mollifiers.

Comment: My goal is to prove the uniqueness of the weak derivative in the easiest way possible

Comment: In order to use an assumption with $\forall \varphi\in C_c^\infty$, one needs a function   in $C_c^\infty$ to which this assumption could be applied. And the standard mollifier is the simplest such function known to the world.

Comment: Is there a proof of the uniqueness of the weak derivative based on Lebesgue´s differentiation theorem?

Comment: Yes, the proof I have in mind uses Lebesgue differentiation. You pick a Lebesgue point of $f$, and build $\varphi$ supported near it. But this $\varphi$ is the same mollifier thing that we use for convolution.